# Passing correct data frame from within dplyr::summarise

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use `dplyr` with my own function which summarises a data frame to a single value. In the example below, `my_func` counts the number of missing values. I could do this specific case another way, but I'm interested in knowing how to do this generally. I need this to work with grouped data. I thought something like this might work:

```
my_func <- function(df) {
  return(sum(is.na(df)))
}

data("airquality")

airquality %>% group_by(Month) %>% summarise(my_func(.))

## # A tibble: 5 × 2
##   Month `my_func(.)`
##   <int>        <int>
## 1     5           44
## 2     6           44
## 3     7           44
## 4     8           44
## 5     9           44
```

But it seems `.` is the whole data frame, not the individual groups.

`dplyr::do` can get the correct data frame:

```
airquality %>% group_by(Month) %>% do(data.frame(m = my_func(.)))

## Source: local data frame [5 x 2]
## Groups: Month [5]
## 
##   Month     m
##   <int> <int>
## 1     5     9
## 2     6    21
## 3     7     5
## 4     8     8
## 5     9     1
```

But this seems like a hack. It's also not consistent with `summarise`, because the output from `do` is still a grouped data frame.

Essentially, my question is: can I pass the correct data frame (respecting groups) to my function from within `summarise`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further checks, it seems that the problem lies with the use of `.` in `summarise`. For example, the following works for a single variable:

`airquality %>% group_by(Month) %>% summarize(my_func(Ozone))`

yet this one doesn't:

`airquality %>% group_by(Month) %>% summarize(my_func(.$Ozone))`

Similarly, explicitly creating a `data.frame` with all the variables gives the desired output:

`airquality %>% 
  group_by(Month) %>% 
  summarize(NAs = my_func(data.frame(Ozone, Solar.R, Wind, Temp, Month, Day)))`

so if you insist on using `dplyr`, you'll need a workaround like that one (or use `do` as you already mentioned). I believe it's the same bug that has been reported here: [dplyr Issue #2752](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2752).

Comment: Thanks very much. I agree it looks like the same bug as you mention. I think this confirms my view that my original idea "should" work and may do in future when the dplyr bug is addressed.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think you can use the following struture:

```
data <- num.missing(lapply(data$Month, my_func))
```

You also can use:

```
object <- data %>% summarise_each(funs(my_func), Month)
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In your first suggestion, I can't find the function `num.missing`. But anyway, I'm looking to do this for a general function, not just the example of counting missing values. Your second suggestion doesn't give the right output when I did `airquality %>% summarise_each(funs(my_func), Month)`, there's no grouping. So I don't see how this solves it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using the `plyr` package, that seems to produce the desired output:
`plyr::ddply(.data = airquality, .variables = ~ Month, .fun = my_func)`

Comment: Thanks, that does work. I am more interested in understanding why this doesn't work in `dplyr` though, or an alternative use of `dplyr` that can achieve this, as I believe it's something that should be possible in the package.